# Specify the order Dockers run on Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run two Dockers on the same Kubernetes pod and I want one of the Docker container always to run before the other. I remember learning about specifying such dependency on the pod configuration file, but can not find that now. Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod) does not explain it either.

Here is the example pod configuration with two containers I adopted from another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741479/how-to-write-a-kubernetes-pod-configuration-to-start-two-containers). How should I change this pod configuration to run container `type1` before `type2`?

```
{
  "id": "podId",
  "desiredState": {
    "manifest": {
      "version": "v1beta1",
      "id": "podId",
      "containers": [{
        "name": "type1",
        "image": "local/image"
        },
        {
        "name": "type2",
        "image": "local/secondary"
        }]
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "name": "imageTest"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Nodir.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kubernetes currently does not allow specification of container startup dependencies.

There has been some discussion in GitHub issues [1996](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/1996) and [1589](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/1589) that might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Answering on 2021,

Now, it is possible by using [`Init Containers,`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) if your first container is meant for doing initialization for the second container,

> In Kubernetes, an init container is the one that starts and executes
> before other containers in the same Pod. It’s meant to perform
> initialization logic for the main application hosted on the Pod. For
> example, create the necessary user accounts, perform database
> migrations, create database schemas and so on.

On how to use: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container

**Yet another [interesting read](https://medium.com/@marko.luksa/delaying-application-start-until-sidecar-is-ready-2ec2d21a7b74) if both of them are application containers and you want kubelet to deploy sequentially.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use an init container to block one pod and wait for another one. You could use [bitnami/kubectl](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl/) as init container with the --wait flag. Alternatively you could use a [custom wait job](https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for).

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: start-first
      labels:
        name: start-first
    spec: &nginx
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: start-second
      labels:
        name: start-second
    spec:
      <<: *nginx
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-first
          image: bitnami/kubectl
          args:
            - wait
            - pod/start-first
            - --for
            - condition=Ready
            - --timeout
            - 60s
```

You may have to give the init container a particular role like stated [here](https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for#troubleshooting). That depends on your security setup.

Also note that having it in a list isn't required. I just use it to be able to use the anchor for brevity.